# SQL To Find All Descendents

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a data table like this

```
 Entities:
 ID | Parent_ID
 1  | null
 2  | 1
 3  | 1
 4  | 3
 5  | 4
 6  | 4
```

I'd like a sql expression that will return a row for every entity and a linear descendant, plus a row for null if the entity has no descendants. So given the above data my result set would be:

```
Entity | Descendant
1      | 2
1      | 3
1      | 4
1      | 5
1      | 6
2      | null
3      | 4
3      | 5
3      | 6
4      | 5
5      | null
6      | null
```

I tried using a common table expression to achieve this, and think it's the way to do it, given its ability to recurse, but I couldn't get my head wrapped around the spawning of many rows for a single parent.

```
with all_my_children (my_father,my_id,my_descendant,level)
as
(   
    select parent_id,id,null,0
    from Entities
    where id not in (select parent_id from entities)
    union all
    select e.parent_id,e.id,amc.my_id,amc.level+1 
    from Entities e
    inner join all_my_children amc 
    on e.id = amc.my_father
    WHERE ????? --How do I know when I'm done? and How do I keep repeating parents for each descendant?

)

select my_id, my_descendant from all_my_children
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's different about mine is the output format. That accepted answer gives the result as a single row, with a comma delimited string of descendents. I don't want to have to split that string. I need a row for each. Also, that example works with a given root as input. I need to break the entire table up at once.

Comment: Why don't you try Tree once. Here is good article about how to make tree in sql server. It will make your job easier. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328858/Implementing-multi-level-trees-in-MS-SQL-Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you asked for

```
WITH TEMP AS
(

    SELECT ID AS ENTITY, PID AS DESCENDANTS
    FROM YPC_BI_TEMP.DBO.SV7104
    WHERE PID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID AS ENTITY, ID AS DESCENDANTS
    FROM YPC_BI_TEMP.DBO.SV7104
    WHERE PID IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PRNT.ENTITY, CHILD.ID  AS DESCENDANTS
    FROM YPC_BI_TEMP.DBO.SV7104 AS CHILD
    INNER JOIN TEMP AS PRNT
    on PRNT.DESCENDANTS = CHILD.PID
    --AND PRNT.ENTITY IS NOT NULL

)
SELECT DISTINCT ENTITY, DESCENDANTS FROM TEMP
UNION
SELECT ID AS ENTITY, NULL AS DESCENDANTS FROM YPC_BI_TEMP.DBO.SV7104
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ENTITY FROM TEMP)
```

Comment: @billgreg modified to display parents with no children

Answer (score 2):

Deleted my previous answer, but I think this might do the trick...

```
WITH all_my_children AS (my_father,my_id,my_descendant,level)
        (
        SELECT  parent_id, id, null, 0
        FROM    Entities
        WHERE   parent_id IS NULL -- the roots of your tree
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  COALESCE(e2.parent_id, e.parent_id), e.id, amc.my_id, amc.level+1
        FROM    Entities e
        JOIN    all_my_children amc
        ON      e.parent_id = amc.my_id
        LEFT JOIN    Entities e2
        ON      e.id = e2.parent_id
        )
SELECT  * FROM  all_my_children
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You aren't allowed to outer join in a recursive part of a CTE. "Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'all_my_children'"